# How to stop permissions inheritance with cmis

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I am currently using cmis to communicate to alfresco,and i want to create folders with cmis but i don't like those folders to inherite permissions so how can i do that with cmis? 
By the way my app is written in java.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could write a rule (one liner JS) on the parent folder which will automatically turn of permissions for every folder that gets created in it. I know it's not CMIS, but this could be a workaround solution.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/library-folder-rules-define-create.html